# using "_" in function vs Method in scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand the difference between those 3. In particular their type.

```
val func0: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = _ + _ + _
//func0: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function>

def method0 (a: Int, b:Int, c:Int) = (_:Int) + (_:Int) + (_:Int)
//method0: (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)(Int, Int, Int) => Int

def method1 (a: Int, b:Int, c:Int) = a + b + c
//method1: (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)Int
```

1. Is there a rule that says that "_" can only be used in function body and not method body ?
2. Can't understand the type of method0, definitely not like func0 ....
3. Why is it different from method1 ?

method0 is a method that takes 3 parameters and return a function that takes a 3-tuples and return an int ? How is that possible ?

Comment: `method0` take 3 parameters and ignores them (they are never referenced) and returns a function just like `func0`.

Comment: how is ```(_:Int) + (_:Int) + (_:Int)``` a synonymous for ```func0``` ?

Comment: Same type signature (takes 3 `Int` input, returns 1 `Int` output). The fact that they both add their parameters is an accident of implementation. One could add, and the other multiply, and they would still have the same type signature.

Comment: When you do something like `_.foo` it is syntax sugar for `x => x.foo` then if you do something like `_ + _`  it is expanded as `(x, y) => x + y`, so in the context of **functions** each new underscore is used to refer to a new variable for the function. In general, many people _(including myself, so take this with a grain of salt)_ recommend do not using this syntax except for very short expressions since it may be confusing _(especially taking into account that `_` have many meanings in the language)_ - For a method this doesn't makes sense since you have to name your parameters anyways.

Comment: Yeah many thanks, appreciated the` clarification. I just did not link it with what we do in anonymous function most of the time. And yes i never use that ```_ + _``` . One underscore only.